# Edit html file in the .sh script

Tags: shell, sh

I have static **html** file at 'docs/index.html' with ~ 200 lines of code.
I need to add **html tags** to it in 2 places with .sh script. I know there is command **sed**
to edit files, but can't figure out how it is used.

I need to add

`<li><a class="reference" href="#front-end-docs">Front end documentation</a></li>`

before the

`<li><a class="reference internal" href="#indices-and-tables">`

or append my tag to the end of the line number **137**

and of course, save the file after that :)

And a similar tag in another place. Can you please give me an example on how to with this specific lines of code to insert?

*Thanks*

Comment: This looks pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7764055/1983854

Comment: Downvoter, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see if I understand your question correctly:

```
$ cat testfile
one
two
<li><a class="reference internal" href="#indices-and-tables">
four
five

$ sed '3s|\(.*\)|<li><a class="reference" href="#front-end-docs">Front end documentation</a></li>\1|' testfile
one
two
<li><a class="reference" href="#front-end-docs">Front end documentation</a></li><li><a class="reference internal" href="#indices-and-tables">
four
five
```

Exchange the `3s` with the line number in question, e.g. `137s` - this tells `sed` which line you want the substitution to occur.
You wrote *add before or append*, so I am not sure if you actually meant to append the string or prepend it to the line, so move the `\1` to wherever you need it. The above command *captures* the whole line `3` which you can reference by `\1` in your replacement string.

Once it gives the desired output, add the `-i` switch to `sed` to overwrite the original file.